# Norm of curvature 2-form in coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics, tensors

#### Set up

Let $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ with Euclidean metric. Suppose $F \in \Omega^2(M)$ is an 2-form (e.g. curvature) and $\phi \in \Omega^1(M)$ be a 1-form. These can be written in coordinates as:

$$F = \sum_{i<j} F_{ij} dx^idx^j \quad \quad \phi = \phi_i dx^i\thinspace .$$

Taking the covariant derivative of $\phi$ we get:

$$F = \sum_{i<j} F_{ij} dx^idx^j \quad \quad \nabla \phi =\sum_{i,j} \nabla_i\phi_j \thinspace dx^i\otimes dx^j\thinspace .$$

**Goal:** Compute the norm of $F$ and $\nabla \phi$ in coordinates.

#### Question

Are the below expressions correct (repeated indices to be summed)?

$$|F|^2 = F_{ij}F^{ij} \quad |\nabla \phi|^2 = \nabla_i\phi_j\nabla^i\phi^j\thinspace .$$

By $F_{ij}F^{ij}$ I think we mean:

$$F_{ij}F^{ij} = \sum_{i,j} F_{ij}F^{ij}\thinspace .$$

#### Confusion

In an article the authors consider the following action:

$$ \mathscr{A} = \int_M d^4x \left(\frac{1}{2} F_{ij}F^{ij} + \nabla_i\phi_j\nabla^i\phi^j \right)\thinspace .$$

So do they mean

1. $ \mathscr{A} = \int_M d^4x \left(\frac{1}{2} |F|^2 + |\nabla \phi|^2 \right)\thinspace$ OR
2. $ \mathscr{A} = \int_M d^4x \left(|F|^2 + |\nabla \phi|^2 \right)\thinspace ?$

**Upshot:** Confused by a factor of 2, all help is appreciated.

Comment: The authors mean $$\mathscr{A} = \int_M d^4x \left(\frac{1}{2} F_{ij}F^{ij} + \nabla_i\phi_j\nabla^i\phi^j \right)\thinspace$$ with $i,j$ summed.  What has this all to do with one- and two-forms which you explain to us in a very strange way? About 1. and 2. they probably mean 1. However: if they do not use that notation why bother?

Comment: @KurtG. I am beginner and I am more used to coordinate free notation like $|F|^2$. The authors write everything in terms of repeated indices and I'm just trying to compare their notation with what I am most familiar with. They further apply integration by parts while I am only familar with applying Stoke's theorem on forms. So I was trying to convert everything to forms via $\langle a, b \rangle d^4x = a\wedge \ast b$.

Comment: If you are familiar with forms I'd recommend to write $\boldsymbol{F}=F_{ij}\,dx^i\otimes dx^j\,.$ Presumably, $F_{ij}$ is anti-symmetric which makes this tensor a two-form. Likewise, assuming $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ is the one-form $\boldsymbol{\phi}=\phi_i\,dx^i$ and $\nabla_i$ is an ordinary partial derivative, then the authors' $\nabla_i\phi_j$ are the components of the two-form $d\boldsymbol{\phi}=\nabla_i\phi_j\,dx^i\wedge dx^j\,.$ In physics tensor contractions are used a lot and it is easier to understand them as those authors wrote them. You should convince yourself that the scalars

Comment: $F_{ij}F^{ij}$ and $\nabla_i\phi_j\,\nabla^i\phi^j$ do not depend on the chosen coordinates. Lastly: Roger Penrose has invented abstract index notation to enable tensor contractions without coordinates. Interesting but not necessary for beginners reading physics literature.